# How to capture installation path?

Tags: visual-c++

How to capture user selected installation path?

I know that I can get the "Program Files" path from %PROGRAMFILES%, but how can I get the user selected installation path?

Comment: What do you mean by installation path, do you mean the path where your executable is located?

Comment: What I meant by installation path, is the path that the user selected during the setup GUI. Since, my program is hardcoded to 'c:\\programfiles', it cannot run if the user install my program at different path. So I need to make my reference path dynamic inside my program :)

Comment: please clarify which app is being installed and which app needs to know where it was installed. Or are you talking about the same app?

Comment: I have a dll and a exe. The dll is registered using regsvr32. The dll need to call the exe in order to work. So, I need to program the path of the exe's location inside my dll.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done using    `GetCurrentPath(CurrentPath);`

```
// The Code is Borland's, I just modified it
// to make it Standard C++

#include <direct.h>        // for getcwd
#include <stdlib.h>        // for MAX_PATH
#include <iostream>        // for cout and cin

using namespace std;

// function to return the current working directory
// this is generally the application path
void GetCurrentPath(char* buffer)
{
getcwd(buffer, _MAX_PATH);
}

int main()
{

// _MAX_PATH is the maximum length allowed for a path
char CurrentPath[_MAX_PATH];
// use the function to get the path
GetCurrentPath(CurrentPath);

// display the path for demo purposes only
char temp[_MAX_PATH];
cout << CurrentPath << endl;
cout << "Press Enter to continue";
cin.getline(temp,_MAX_PATH);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does this means that I can simply substitute the "c:\\Programfiles" part with the return value of getcwd?

Comment: It works. But does not exactly detect the path of the installed files.

Answer (score 1):

I think the installer could be modified to write it to a registry key for later reference.

Comment: any idea how to modify visual studio installer to do this?

Comment: @karikari, no that's Microsoft's property not open source! I meant modify the installer of the app whose installation path you want to retrieve later for another program (the one that needs it). My answer assumes that's what you're trying to do (ie. App A needs to know where App B is installed)

Comment: yes Sam. Actually, I built a DLL that is working with a external exe. My problem is, I cant track the installation path that the user selected. Currently, I hardcoded the path for the exe inside my DLL. When a user installed the exe to other folder, my dll cant find it :(

Comment: Well, if you know the name of the exe you can search for it. Otherwise like I suggested, modify the installer of the exe to write the installation path to a registry key. Then your dll can always know the exe's location by reading that registry key.

Comment: You could even go further and modify the exe's code to update that registry key everytime it (the exe) is executed. That way if the exe is moved around it will update the registry key automatically. If you can't modify the exe or its installer, I think searching by filename is your only option.